# Need help checking input for 2D matrix with python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I need to find how to check if the input, which is a list, is 2D with the same amount of columns as rows and the same amount of parts in them. Example: `[[4,5],[4,5,6]] and [[2,3],[6,1],[2,9]]` would generate error messages. But `[[3,4,5],[4,6,8],[5,8,-1]] and [[4,5],[4,1]]` would be correct.
I have tried:

```
    for row in square:
        if len(row) != len(square):
            return False
```

but that doesn't work quite right.

EDIT: Also this check is at the start of a list of checks, so it need to be in a if statement format.

Comment: "but that doesn't work quite right" -- Why not?  Can you give an example where it isn't working right?  What error or unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: You might try more succinctly `len(set(len(row) for row in square)) == 1` to see if each row has an equal number of columns.

Comment: @WaleedKhan -- That doesn't have OP's short circuiting behavior, and it doesn't assert that the row length == the column length and finally, I find it to be a rather round-about way to do it. if you're looking for a 1 liner, I'd propose `all(len(row) == len(matrix) for row in matrix)`.  But that still doesn't answer the question of what OP thinks is wrong with the original solution.

Comment: @mgilson You're right on all counts; I'll try to avoid that sort of thing in the future. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a return value if the test is not failed? Putting your code in a function, assuming there's nothing more to the test:

```
def matrix_test(square):
    for row in square:
        if len(row) != len(square):
             return False
```

...either returns False or <strike>doesn't return a value</strike> returns None. So if you test a matrix by calling this function, you will never get a True result for the matrices that pass the test. So if it's not already there, add the final line:

```
    return True
```

You can then check a particular matrix with

```
if matrix_test(matrix001):
    #run the next test
```

If that's not the problem it would help to see more of the code, and to know what happens when it runs.

Comment: Ahh, I just assumed the `return True` was in there.  Good catch.  One minor nitpick -- "doesn't return a value" isn't quite correct.  If no return statement is hit in a function (or a bare `return`), then python implicitly returns the special singleton `None`.

Comment: @mgilson - Your nitpick is a fair comment. I suspected that I was being imprecise about `None`, but I also knew that being more specific would expose my knowledge deficit even more... Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In a boolean context, `None` evaluates to `False`, so, `if None:` and `if False:` are the same.  In this case, it's likely OP is falling through his function and the result is always "false-like".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix is a sequence that holds other sequences (like a list of lists as you have in your question), you could simply do something like:

```
def is_square(matrix):
    return all(len(row) == len(matrix) for row in matrix)
```